# Is there any way to shutdown `tokio::runtime::current_thread::Runtime`?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm using [`tokio::runtime::current_thread::Runtime`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.13/tokio/runtime/current_thread/index.html) and I want to able to run a future and stop the reactor in the same thread. The example on the page doesn't show how to stop the runtime. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: I believe that would entail stopping the current running thread i.e. the program entirely. You'd have to spawn a separate thread for the runtime and stop it from the main thread or just exit it [https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html]()

Answer (score 3):

The runtime will automatically shut down when when the future is complete:

```
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time; // 0.2.21

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    time::delay_for(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
    eprintln!("future complete");
}
```

See [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423) for other ways of creating a runtime.

---

If you need to cancel a future, you can create something that will cause future `poll`s to succeed. I'd probably use channels and `select`:

```rust
use futures::{channel::oneshot, future, FutureExt}; // 0.3.5
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::{task, time}; // 0.2.21

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let future = async {
        time::delay_for(Duration::from_secs(3600)).await;
        eprintln!("future complete");
    };

    let (cancel_tx, cancel_rx) = oneshot::channel();

    let another_task = task::spawn(async {
        eprintln!("Another task started");
        time::delay_for(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
        eprintln!("Another task canceling the future");
        cancel_tx.send(()).expect("Unable to cancel");
        eprintln!("Another task exiting");
    });

    future::select(future.boxed(), cancel_rx).await;

    another_task.await.expect("The other task panicked");
}
```

Here's an alternate manual solution that's very simple, brute force, and probably not-very-performant:

```
use pin_project::pin_project; // 0.4.17
use std::{
    future::Future,
    pin::Pin,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    task::{self, Context, Poll},
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};
use tokio::time; // 0.2.21 

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let future = async {
        time::delay_for(Duration::from_secs(3600)).await;
        eprintln!("future complete");
    };

    let (future, cancel) = Cancelable::new(future);

    let another_thread = thread::spawn(|| {
        eprintln!("Another thread started");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        eprintln!("Another thread canceling the future");
        cancel();
        eprintln!("Another thread exiting");
    });

    future.await;

    another_thread.join().expect("The other thread panicked");
}

#[pin_project]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cancelable<F> {
    #[pin]
    inner: F,
    info: Arc<Mutex<CancelInfo>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct CancelInfo {
    cancelled: bool,
    task: Option<task::Waker>,
}

impl<F> Cancelable<F> {
    fn new(inner: F) -> (Self, impl FnOnce()) {
        let info = Arc::new(Mutex::new(CancelInfo::default()));
        let cancel = {
            let info = info.clone();
            move || {
                let mut info = info.lock().unwrap();
                info.cancelled = true;
                if let Some(waker) = info.task.take() {
                    waker.wake();
                }
            }
        };
        let me = Cancelable { inner, info };
        (me, cancel)
    }
}

impl<F> Future for Cancelable<F>
where
    F: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let this = self.project();
        let mut info = this.info.lock().unwrap();

        if info.cancelled {
            Poll::Ready(())
        } else {
            let r = this.inner.poll(ctx);

            if r.is_pending() {
                info.task = Some(ctx.waker().clone());
            }

            r
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [When is it safe to move a member value out of a pinned future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56058494/155423)