# When is it safe to move a member value out of a pinned future?

Tags: rust, future

I'm writing a future combinator that needs to consume a value that it was provided with. With futures 0.1, [`Future::poll`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.26/futures/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) took `self: &mut Self`, which effectively meant that my combinator contained an `Option` and I  called `Option::take` on it when the underlying future resolves.

The [`Future::poll`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) method in the standard library takes `self: Pin<&mut Self>` instead, so I've been reading about the guarantees required in order to safely make use of `Pin`.

From the `pin` module documentation on the [`Drop` guarantee](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/pin/index.html#drop-guarantee) (emphasis mine):

> Concretely, for pinned data you have to maintain the invariant that its memory will not get invalidated from the moment it gets pinned until when drop is called. Memory can be invalidated by deallocation, but also by **replacing a `Some(v)` by `None`**, or calling `Vec::set_len` to "kill" some elements off of a vector.

And [Projections and Structural Pinning](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/pin/index.html#projections-and-structural-pinning) (emphasis mine):

> You must not offer any other operations that could lead to data being moved out of the fields when your type is pinned. For example, if the wrapper contains an `Option<T>` and there is a **take-like operation** with type `fn(Pin<&mut Wrapper<T>>) -> Option<T>`, that operation can be used to move a `T` out of a pinned `Wrapper<T>` -- which means pinning cannot be structural.

However, the existing [`Map`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/blob/0.3.0-alpha.15/futures-util/src/future/map.rs#L36-L45) combinator calls `Option::take` on a member value when the underlying future has resolved:

```
fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<T> {
    match self.as_mut().future().poll(cx) {
        Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
        Poll::Ready(output) => {
            let f = self.f().take()
                .expect("Map must not be polled after it returned `Poll::Ready`");
            Poll::Ready(f(output))
        }
    }
}
```

The `f` method is generated by the [`unsafe_unpinned`](https://docs.rs/pin-utils/0.1.0-alpha.4/pin_utils/macro.unsafe_unpinned.html) macro and looks roughly like:

```
fn f<'a>(self: Pin<&'a mut Self>) -> &'a mut Option<F> {
    unsafe { &mut Pin::get_unchecked_mut(self).f }
}
```

It *appears* that `Map` violates the requirements that are described in the `pin` documentation, but I believe that the authors of the `Map` combinator know what they are doing and that this code is safe.

What logic allows them to perform this operation in a safe manner?

Comment: If you have not already, I would encourage you to make a post on either URLO or IRLO. The question is tricky enough that I would not mind the opinion of experts (withoutboats, notably) to set my mind at ease. I have a feeling that it's safe (`Pin` only being about stability over suspension points), but...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is all about structural pinning.

First, I will use the syntax `P<T>` to mean something like `impl Deref<Target = T>` — some (smart) pointer type `P` that `Deref::deref`s to a `T`. `Pin` only "applies" to / makes sense on such (smart) pointers.

Let's say we have:

```rust
struct Wrapper<Field> {
    field: Field,
}
```

The initial question is

> Can we get a `Pin<P<Field>>` from a `Pin<P<Wrapper<Field>>>`, by "projecting" our `Pin<P<_>>` from the `Wrapper` to its `field`?

This requires the basic projection `P<Wrapper<Field>> -> P<Field>`, which is only possible for:

- shared references (`P<T> = &T`). This is not a very interesting case given that `Pin<P<T>>` always [`deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref)s to `T`.
- unique references (`P<T> = &mut T`).

I will use the syntax `&[mut] T` for this type of projection.

The question now becomes:

> Can we go from `Pin<&[mut] Wrapper<Field>>` to `Pin<&[mut] Field>`?

The point that may be unclear from the documentation is that it is up to the creator of `Wrapper` to decide!

There are two possible choices for the library author for each struct field.

### There is a structural `Pin` projection to that field

For instance, the [`pin_utils::unsafe_pinned!`](https://docs.rs/pin-utils/0.1.0-alpha.4/pin_utils/macro.unsafe_pinned.html) macro is used to define such a projection (`Pin<&mut Wrapper<Field>> -> Pin<&mut Field>`).

For the `Pin` projection to be sound:

- the whole struct must only implement `Unpin` when all the fields for which there is a structural `Pin` projection implement `Unpin`.

  - no implementation is allowed to use `unsafe` to move such fields out of a `Pin<&mut Wrapper<Field>>` (or `Pin<&mut Self>` when `Self = Wrapper<Field>`). For instance, **`Option::take()` is forbidden**.
- the whole struct may only implement `Drop` if `Drop::drop` does not move any of the fields for which there is a structural projection.
- the struct cannot be `#[repr(packed)]` (a corollary of the previous item).

In your given [`future::Map`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/blob/0.3.0-alpha.15/futures-util/src/future/map.rs#L36-L45) example, this is the case of the `future` field of the `Map` struct.

### There is no structural `Pin` projection to that field

For instance, the [`pin_utils::unsafe_unpinned!`](https://docs.rs/pin-utils/0.1.0-alpha.4/pin_utils/macro.unsafe_unpinned.html) macro is used to define such a projection (`Pin<&mut Wrapper<Field>> -> &mut Field`).

In this case, *that field* is not considered pinned by a `Pin<&mut Wrapper<Field>>`.

- whether `Field` is `Unpin` or not does not matter.

  - implementations are allowed to use `unsafe` to move such fields out of a `Pin<&mut Wrapper<Field>>`. For instance, **`Option::take()` is allowed**.
- `Drop::drop` is also allowed to move such fields,

In your given [`future::Map`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/blob/0.3.0-alpha.15/futures-util/src/future/map.rs#L36-L45) example, this is the case of the `f` field of the `Map` struct.

#### Example of both types of projection

```rust
impl<Fut, F> Map<Fut, F> {
    unsafe_pinned!(future: Fut); // pin projection -----+
    unsafe_unpinned!(f: Option<F>); // not pinned --+   |
//                                                  |   |
//                 ...                              |   |
//                                                  |   |
    fn poll (mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<T> {
        //                                          |   |
        match self.as_mut().future().poll(cx) { // <----+ required here
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending, //      |
            Poll::Ready(output) => { //             |
                let f = self.f().take() // <--------+ allows this
```

Comment: It would be helpful to mention _why_ `Map` chooses not to have a pin projection to `f`. Any self-referential `F` will be invalidated during `poll` causing UB. I think the answer is that the user observes `f` being moved into `Map` upon construction (thus invalidating any internal references) and we don't need to do anything with `f` until after `take` is called, so treating `f` as pinned (and then requiring `F: Unpin` everywhere) doesn't add anything: `T: Unpin` only has semantic value when a `Pin<P<T>>` exists. It would, however, lint if people try to pass a self-referential `f` into `Map`.

Comment: Although I guess the whole point of `Pin`/`Unpin` versus (a hypothetical) `!Move` is that we don't want it to infect all APIs where a move occurs.

Comment: @ecstaticm0rse yes, this is a good example of `Pin` not being `!Move`. The only thing that needs to be pinned here is the inner future, wrapped in `Map`. But given that the only thing actually pinned (when polled) is the outermost wrapper, the pin projection is needed to guarantee the "transitivity"  of the Pin applying to the inner future.
In all this business the closure is just a good old value safely moved into the structure; it would only be possible for it to be self-referential if it already dealt with it on its own (_e.g._, behind a pointer (`F = Pin<Box<...>>`)), as usual.

Comment: Or in other words: worst case scenario, `F : !Unpin`, which means that once behind a `Pin`ned pointer, the closure cannot move out. But given the lack of `Pin` projection in the `Map` case, it is actually never pinned: **sitting next to a pinned value** does not semantically `Pin` you; you can always stand up and leave (leaving a `Noone` [here] note behind :) ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've made some stylistic edits, please check to make sure I haven't lost any meaning. Can you explain why you've grouped "use `unsafe` to move" underneath the `Unpin` bullet? What's the specific relation between those two points?

Comment: When you get a `Pin<&mut Wrapper<_>>` (and you don't know if it is`Unpin`), if you want to move _anything_ out of the struct you need `&mut _` references and thus need to use `unsafe` (actually, with interior mutability you could move out using a `& _` reference, but it is alsto the reason why wrappers with interior mutability **cannot** offer structural pinning, thus ruling out the first bullet situation). Hence my _use `unsafe` to move_ phrasing.

Such usage of `unsafe` is sound _only in two cases_: when not moving, or when dealing with a non structurally-pinned field.

Answer (score 5):

**edit**: This answer is incorrect. It remains here for posterity.

Let's begin by recalling why `Pin` was introduced in the first place: we want to statically ensure that self-referential futures cannot be moved, thus invalidating their internal references.

With that in mind, let's take a look at the definition of `Map`.

```
pub struct Map<Fut, F> {
    future: Fut,
    f: Option<F>,
}
```

`Map` has two fields, the first one stores a future, the second stores a closure which maps the result of that future to another value. We wish to support storing self-referential types directly in `future` without placing them behind a pointer. This means that if `Fut` is a self-referential type, `Map` cannot be moved once it is constructed. That is why we must use `Pin<&mut Map>` as the receiver for `Future::poll`. If a normal mutable reference to a `Map` containing a self-referential future was ever exposed to an implementor of `Future`, users could cause UB using only safe code by causing the `Map` to be moved using `mem::replace`.

However, we don't need to support storing self-referential types in `f`. If we assume that the self-referential part of a `Map` is wholly contained in `future`, we can freely modify `f` as long as we don't allow `future` to be moved.

While a self-referential closure would be very unusual, the assumption that `f` be safe to move (which is equivalent to `F: Unpin`) is not explicitly stated anywhere. However, we still move the value in `f` in `Future::poll` by calling `take`! I think this is indeed a bug, but I'm not 100% sure. I think the `f()` getter should require `F: Unpin` which would mean `Map` can only implement `Future` when the closure argument is safe to be moved from behind a `Pin`.

It's very possible that I'm overlooking some subtleties in the pin API here, and the implementation is indeed safe. I'm still wrapping my head around it as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. *I think this is indeed a bug, but I'm not 100% sure* — is there some way that you could remove any doubt one way or the other?

Comment: Putting `F: Unpin` isn't necessary, because it has an `F: FnOnce(Fut::Output) -> T` bound, and closures are always `Unpin` (at least for now). Though putting `F: Unpin` probably doesn't hurt anything either.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it. It *is* possible for a closure to be `!Unpin` if it closes over `!Unpin` values. So it may indeed be a bug to not require `F: Unpin`!

Comment: @Pauan: The `FnOnce` seems to limit the observability here. One of the key points of `Pin` is to pin a value in memory across suspension points, however even if `F` closes over a `!Unpin` value, this value is never accessed across suspension points, it's only accessed once.