# No method named `poll` found for a type that implements `Future`

Tags: rust, future

I am attempting to create a struct that will allow someone to call `.shutdown()`, which will resolve a future (that is otherwise pending). It can only be called once. In the implementation of the `Future` trait, I receive an error that `poll` is not defined, despite it being present in [the documentation](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.17/futures/channel/oneshot/struct.Receiver.html#implementations) (under `impl Future`).

Though I am using `std::future::Future` as the `impl`, I tried adding `use futures::prelude::*`, which would bring the preview trait into scope. Both RLS and rustc inform me that the import is unused, so that's not the issue.

Note that I am *not* using a simple boolean flag, as I intend for this to be able to be callable from any thread — that's an implementation detail that is irrelevant here.

```rust
use futures::channel::oneshot; // futures-preview@0.3.0-alpha.17
use std::{
    future::Future,
    pin::Pin,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};

pub struct ShutdownHandle {
    sender: oneshot::Sender<()>,
    receiver: oneshot::Receiver<()>,
}

impl ShutdownHandle {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel();
        Self { sender, receiver }
    }

    pub fn shutdown(self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        self.sender.send(())
    }
}

impl Future for ShutdownHandle {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        self.receiver.poll(&mut cx).map(|_| ())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let runner = ShutdownHandle::new();
    assert!(runner.shutdown().is_ok());
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `poll` found for type `futures_channel::oneshot::Receiver<()>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:28:23
   |
28 |         self.receiver.poll(&mut cx).map(|_| ())
   |                       ^^^^
```

What am I missing? Surely there's some way to "pass through" the polling. I am using nightly (2019-07-18).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's true, `Receiver` does not implement `Future`; only **`Pin<&mut Receiver>`** does. You need to *project* the pinning from your type to the field.

### When the underlying type may not implement `Unpin`

```
impl Future for ShutdownHandle {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        // I copied this code from Stack Overflow without reading the text that
        // told me how to verify that this code uses `unsafe` correctly.
        unsafe { self.map_unchecked_mut(|s| &mut s.receiver) }.poll(cx).map(|_| ())
    }
}
```

You must read the [`pin` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#projections-and-structural-pinning) to thoroughly understand the requirements to use `unsafe` here.

#### A cleaner solution

I like to use a helper library, such as [pin_project](https://docs.rs/pin-project/0.3.4/pin_project/), to handle more complicated types of projection:

```
#[unsafe_project(Unpin)]
pub struct ShutdownHandle {
    #[pin]
    sender: oneshot::Sender<()>,
    #[pin]
    receiver: oneshot::Receiver<()>,
}

impl Future for ShutdownHandle {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let this = self.project();
        this.receiver.poll(cx).map(|_| ())
    }
}
```

### When the underlying type implements `Unpin`

[Ömer Erden points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57369123/no-method-named-poll-found-for-a-type-that-implements-future/57377607?noredirect=1#comment101240159_57377607) that the futures-preview crate provides [`FutureExt::poll_unpin`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.17/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.poll_unpin). This method takes a mutable reference to a type that implements [`Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html) and creates a brand new `Pin` with it.

Since `oneshot::Receiver` does implement `Unpin`, this can be used here:

```
impl Future for ShutdownHandle {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        self.receiver.poll_unpin(cx).map(|_| ())
    }
}
```

### See also

- [When is it safe to move a member value out of a pinned future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56058494/155423)
- [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423)

Comment: _It's true, Receiver does not implement Future; only Pin<&mut Receiver> does._ In this case using `poll_unpin` would be a quicker solution but not sure is there any pitfall using `poll_unpin` or not. I would like to know if it is applicable for this problem ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden In this specific situation, that certainly seems to be the simpler solution, and avoids using `unsafe` (at least directly). Thanks for that!

Comment: For future reference for myself and anyone else: Keep in mind that you may get this error even if you're implementing the trait, as there's currently a transition from 0.1 to 0.3 Futures. Hopefully this transition period will be relatively short, but this is due to the same reason linked in the answer.