# How do I use Pin with Tokio's Sink?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I would like to create a method sending some data on a struct which implements Tokio's [`Sink`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.0-alpha.1/tokio/prelude/trait.Sink.html), but I'm having problems working with `Pin` as self. In essence, I need something like this:

```
fn send_data(&mut self, data: Item, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Result<(), Error>> {
    futures_core::ready!(something.poll_ready(cx))?;
    something.start_send(data)?;
    futures_core::ready!(something.poll_close(cx))
}
```

The problem is that each call to `poll_ready()`, `start_send()` and `poll_close()` takes `self: Pin<&mut Self>` and I don't know what `something` in my use case should be. If I try to use `let something = Pin::new(self);` then `something` gets moved after the call to `poll_ready()` and I cannot use it for subsequent calls (self is also gone at this point). How do I work around this problem?

```
use futures_core;
use std::pin::Pin;
use tokio::prelude::*; // 0.3.0-alpha.1

struct Test {}

impl Sink<i32> for Test {
    type Error = ();

    fn poll_ready(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }

    fn start_send(self: Pin<&mut Self>, item: i32) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn poll_flush(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }

    fn poll_close(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}

impl Test {
    fn send_data(&mut self, data: i32, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Result<(), Error>> {
        // what should "something" here be?
        futures_core::ready!(something.poll_ready(cx))?;
        something.start_send(data)?;
        futures_core::ready!(something.poll_close(cx))
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [No method named `poll` found for a type that implements `Future`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57369123/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Why don't you take `self: Pin<&mut Self>` instead of `&mut Self`?

Comment: That propagated the problem upwards, but I managed to work around it (not yet sure why it works, need to digest it a bit): https://gist.github.com/rust-play/83bc9a87f9bca8b4af5ec4fbe44f7263

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to Rust myself (just started this week), but I [solved a very similar problem](https://github.com/debate-map/app/blob/afc6467b6c6c961f7bcc7b7f901f0ff5cd79d440/Packages/app-server-rs/src/pgclient.rs#L96) earlier today by doing the following:

1. Create a pinned version of `something`: `let mut something_pinned = Box::pin(something);`
2. Call `.as_mut()` before each call to `poll_ready`, `start_send`, and `poll_close`.

So in your `send_data`, it should look something like:

```
futures_core::ready!(something_pinned.as_mut().poll_ready(cx))?;
something_pinned.as_mut().start_send(data)?;
futures_core::ready!(something_pinned.as_mut().poll_close(cx))
```

Also, I think you're generally supposed to store "memory" of which of your sub-poll steps have already been completed, eg. so that when your function gets re-called, it doesn't call `start_send` additional times after having already seen it succeed/become-ready. (though maybe it doesn't cause any actual problems to call it redundantly in this case)