# How can I wrap a dynamically typed stream for API convenience?

Tags: rust, rust-futures

I'm looking to implement a wrapper struct for any stream that returns a certain type, to cut down on the dynamic keywords littering my application. I've come across `BoxStream`, but have no idea how to make use of it in `Stream::poll_next`. Here's what I have so far:

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use futures::prelude::stream::BoxStream;
use futures::Stream;

pub struct Row;

pub struct RowCollection<'a> {
    stream: BoxStream<'a, Row>,
}

impl RowCollection<'_> {
    pub fn new<'a>(stream: BoxStream<Row>) -> RowCollection {
        RowCollection { stream }
    }
}

impl Stream for RowCollection<'_> {
    type Item = Row;
    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        // I have no idea what to put here, but it needs to get the information from self.stream and return appropriate value
    }
}
```

### Dependencies:

futures = "0.3"

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what dynamic keywords you're referring to, but perhaps `pub type RowCollection<'a> = BoxStream<'a, Row>` is a simpler way of achieving your goal?

Comment: BoxStream<'a, T> is shorthand for a stream that has a dynamic type, from what I've gathered from the docs.

Comment: That's correct - the type that implements the stream is dynamic and determined at run-time. The type of stream's item is statically known. As far as I can tell, your wrapping of `BoxStream<Row>` is trivial and can be equally accomplished with a type alias.

Comment: Yeah, for this trivial example an alias will probably work best. I also appreciate the answer by Shepmaster because it shows how to do exactly what I asked, just in case I need to add extra functionality. I'm going to play with both of these suggestions today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`Box` implements `Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Unpin), then `BoxStream` implements `Unpin`, and so will `RowCollection`.

Because of this, you can make use of [`Pin::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.get_mut) which will give you a `&mut RowCollection`. From that, you can get a `&mut BoxStream`. You can re-pin that via `Pin::new` and then call `poll_next` on it. This is called [*pin-projection*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/index.html#projections-and-structural-pinning).

```rust
impl Stream for RowCollection<'_> {
    type Item = Row;
    
    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        Pin::new(&mut self.get_mut().stream).poll_next(cx)
    }
}
```

See also:

- [No method named `poll` found for a type that implements `Future`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57369123/155423)