# How can I create a stream where the items are based on items that the stream previously returned?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stream, future

I have a function that generates a `futures::Stream` based on an argument. I want to call this function multiple times and flatten the streams together. Complicating matters is the fact that I want to feed the values returned by the stream back as the argument to the original function.

Concretely, I have a function that returns a stream of numbers down to zero:

```
fn numbers_down_to_zero(v: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter((0..v).rev())
}
```

I want to call this function starting at 5. The function should also be called for every odd value that is returned. The total set of calls to `numbers_down_to_zero` would be:

```
numbers_down_to_zero(5);
numbers_down_to_zero(3);
numbers_down_to_zero(1);
numbers_down_to_zero(1);
```

Producing the total stream of

```
4
3
2
1
0
2
1
0
0
0
```

What techniques exist to allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By (ab)using async / await, the [`genawaiter` crate](https://crates.io/crates/genawaiter) manages to mimic generator syntax in stable Rust today. Combined with `futures::pin_mut` to pin value on the stack, here is a solution both allocation-free and compatible with arbitrary streams:

```
//# futures = "0.3"
//# genawaiter = { version = "0.2", features = ["futures03"] }
//# tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
use futures::{
    pin_mut,
    stream::{self, Stream, StreamExt},
};
use genawaiter::{generator_mut, stack::Co};
use std::collections::VecDeque;

async fn g(n: i32, co: Co<'_, i32>) {
    let mut seeds = VecDeque::from(vec![n]);
    while let Some(seed) = seeds.pop_back() {
        let stream = f(seed);
        pin_mut!(stream);
        while let Some(x) = stream.next().await {
            if x % 2 != 0 {
                seeds.push_front(x);
            }
            co.yield_(x).await;
        }
    }
}

fn f(n: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter((0..n).rev())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    generator_mut!(stream, |co| g(5, co));
    stream
        .for_each(|v| async move {
            println!("v: {}", v);
        })
        .await;
}
```

Some drawbacks:

- there is one unsafe call inside `generator_mut` macro
- the interface is a bit leaky. The callers get to see some implementation details.

With one heap allocation, [`genawaiter::rc::Gen`](https://docs.rs/genawaiter/0.2.2/genawaiter/rc/struct.Gen.html) can get rid of all these. But again, with allocation on the table there are other options.

```
use futures::{
    pin_mut,
    stream::{Stream, StreamExt},
};
use genawaiter::rc::Gen;
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn g(n: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    Gen::new(|co| async move {
        let mut seeds = VecDeque::from(vec![n]);
        while let Some(seed) = seeds.pop_back() {
            let stream = f(seed);
            pin_mut!(stream);
            while let Some(x) = stream.next().await {
                if x % 2 != 0 {
                    seeds.push_front(x);
                }
                co.yield_(x).await;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this with `unfold`. You'd have a "state" struct that keeps both the "base stream" (in this case counting down towards zero) and the list of items that will produce a new stream, and using that as the argument for `unfold` to keep the state while unfolding.

This way the compiler doesn't have to reason about the lifetime ownership, as the state can be moved into the `async` block for each invocation of the closure.

```rust
/// Base stream (counting down to zero).
fn f(n: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter((0..n).rev())
}

/// "Recursive" stream
fn g(n: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    /// Helper struct to keep state while unfolding
    struct StreamState<S> {
        inner_stream: S,
        item_queue: VecDeque<i32>,
    }

    // Build helper struct
    let state = StreamState {
        inner_stream: f(n),
        item_queue: VecDeque::new(),
    };

    // Unfold with state
    stream::unfold(state, |mut state| async move {
        loop {
            if let Some(item) = state.inner_stream.next().await {
                // Iterate inner stream, and potentially push item to queue
                if item % 2 == 1 {
                    state.item_queue.push_front(item);
                }
                break Some((item, state));
            } else if let Some(item) = state.item_queue.pop_back() {
                // If inner stream is exhausted, produce new stream from queue
                // and repeat loop
                state.inner_stream = f(item);
            } else {
                // If queue is empty, we are done
                break None;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

[Full playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65462f5817cb27aaf912aeed41b60b7a)

[`StreamExt::next`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.next) requires that the inner stream implements `Unpin`, and thus it’s not usable with arbitrary streams. You can always use `Box::pin(stream)` instead, since `Pin<Box<T>>` is `Unpin` and implements `Stream` if `T: Stream`.

Comment: This [requires that the inner stream implements `Unpin`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.next), and thus it’s not usable with arbitrary streams, correct?

Comment: @Shepmaster You can always use `Box::pin(stream)` instead, since `Pin<Box<T>>` is `Unpin` (and implements `Stream` if `T: Stream`).

Comment: Yup (as the docs I linked to suggest), but it shouldn’t be *required* to introduce allocation here as the manual implementation of `Stream` does not require it.

Answer (score 3):

These are partial solutions that I have found, but are lacking for various reasons.

## Using combinators with interior mutability

I don't like this solution because I think that interior mutability should not be required for this general problem, but it is required here because the borrow checker doesn't know how the calls to the closures will interleave.

```
use futures::{stream, Stream, StreamExt};
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn x(v: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter((0..v).rev())
}

use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

fn y0() -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    let to_visit = Rc::new(RefCell::new(VecDeque::from(vec![5])));
    let to_visit_b = to_visit.clone();

    stream::unfold(to_visit, |to_visit| async {
        let i = to_visit.borrow_mut().pop_back()?;

        Some((x(i), to_visit))
    })
    .flatten()
    .inspect(move |&x| {
        if x % 2 != 0 {
            to_visit_b.borrow_mut().push_front(x);
        }
    })
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    y0().for_each(|v| async move {
        println!("v: {}", v);
    })
    .await;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f210458b090aa8eb35e42454695753b1)

## Custom implementation of `Stream::poll_next`

I don't like this solution because it's verbose and requires tricky `unsafe` code that is hard to reason about (I'm not even sure what I have is correct!)

```
use futures::{stream, Stream, StreamExt};
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn x(v: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter((0..v).rev())
}

use std::{
    pin::Pin,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};

struct X<St, C, R, S>
where
    C: Fn(&mut St) -> Option<S>,
    R: Fn(&mut St, &mut S::Item),
    S: Stream,
{
    state: St,
    create: C,
    review: R,
    current: Option<S>,
}

impl<St, C, R, S> Stream for X<St, C, R, S>
where
    C: Fn(&mut St) -> Option<S>,
    R: Fn(&mut St, &mut S::Item),
    S: Stream,
{
    type Item = S::Item;

    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let (state, create, review, current) = unsafe {
            let Self {
                state,
                create,
                review,
                current,
            } = self.get_unchecked_mut();
            (state, create, review, current)
        };

        loop {
            if let Some(current) = current {
                let v = unsafe { futures::ready!(Pin::new_unchecked(current).poll_next(ctx)) };
                if let Some(mut v) = v {
                    review(state, &mut v);
                    return Poll::Ready(Some(v));
                }
            }

            *current = create(state);
            if current.is_none() {
                return Poll::Ready(None);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn y1() -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    X {
        state: VecDeque::from(vec![5]),
        create: |to_visit| {
            let i = to_visit.pop_back()?;

            Some(x(i))
        },
        review: |to_visit, &mut x| {
            if x % 2 != 0 {
                to_visit.push_front(x);
            }
        },
        current: None,
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    y1().for_each(|v| async move {
        println!("v: {}", v);
    })
    .await;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f89e6ed9e878cc6043bf2b18045bd06)

---

## Using channels (non-working)

This doesn't work because the sender is never dropped because the receiver is never dropped because the sender is never dropped ...

Besides not working, this has a number of downsides:

- The state has to implicitly be a queue (which matches what I want to do, but isn't very general).
- It requires that my function become `async` itself to push the initial value to visit.
- I have to handle error conditions that seem irrelevant.
- I have to clone the `Sender` inside of the `then` closure.

```
use futures::{stream, Stream, StreamExt};

fn x(v: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::iter((0..v).rev())
}

use futures::channel::mpsc;
use futures::sink::SinkExt;

async fn y2() -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    let (mut tx, rx) = mpsc::unbounded();

    tx.send(5).await.unwrap();

    rx.map(x).flatten().then(move |x| {
        let mut tx = tx.clone();
        async move {
            if x % 2 != 0 {
                tx.send(x).await.unwrap();
            }
            x
        }
    })
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    y2().await
        .for_each(|v| async move {
            println!("v: {}", v);
        })
        .await;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f39772d3c366767ba6ccfef41e2c3ed)