# How do I use tokio::timer::Timeout with Future::wait?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to introduce a timeout in my RPC requests using [`tokio:timer:Timeout`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.17/tokio/timer/struct.Timeout.html):

```
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer::Delay;

fn main() {
    let when = Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(4000);
    let task = Delay::new(when)
        .and_then(|_| {
            println!("Hello world!");
            Ok(())
        })
        .map_err(|e| panic!("delay errored; err={:?}", e));

    let task_with_timeout = task
        .timeout(Duration::from_millis(3000))
        .map_err(|e| println!("Timeout hit {:?}", e));
    let _ = task_with_timeout.wait().expect("Failure");
    // tokio::run(task_with_timeout);
}
```

If I run my `future_with_timeout` with `tokio::run()`, it works as expected.

However, calling wait on the `task_with_timeout` results in the `task` future getting an error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'delay errored; err=Error(Shutdown)'
```

instead of getting

```
Timeout hit Error(Elapsed)
```

I don't understand the difference here between using `tokio::run()` and `wait()`.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77e06bc351a44c87e37ed1cc9c1f052a)

How do I make the code work using `wait`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't, and it's possible that you just *can't*.

Read the documentation for the `timer` module:

> These types must be used from within the context of the `Runtime` or a timer context must be setup explicitly. See the [tokio-timer crate](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer/0.2.11/tokio_timer/) for more details on how to setup a timer context.

Following the thread, we get to [`tokio_timer::with_default`](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer/0.2.11/tokio_timer/fn.with_default.html) which requires a Tokio executor and a `Timer`. The executor uses the [`Enter`](https://docs.rs/tokio-executor/0.1.7/tokio_executor/struct.Enter.html) type, which itself wants a future to block on.

All of this is to say that Tokio's futures may rely on features outside of the pure *executor*. If I understand the terms correctly (and it's likely I do not), those features are provided by the *reactor*. Calling `wait` has no knowledge of that.

See also:

- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)