# How do I implement an async Drop in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await

I have an `async fn` that returns a type, and want to implement `Drop` on that type that calls another `async` function. It's not clear how to do this, and I can't find anything in the docs. The most illuminating article I found is [Asynchronous Destructors](https://boats.gitlab.io/blog/post/poll-drop/) by withoutboats, but I don't really understand the reasoning, or where this feature is at.

Comment: The point of the article is precisely to said that it's not currently possible. And propose a possible solution, but AFAIK it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It's not clear how to do this, and I can't find anything in the docs

That's because it's not possible; there is no "`async Drop`". `Drop` must be synchronous.

See also:

- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)