# Drop database on drop Using Sqlx and Rust

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

I'm following step by step the [zero2prod Rust book](https://www.zero2prod.com/index.html?country=Spain&discount_code=VAT20). So far, I'm in the last parts of Chapter 3 in which we setup some integration tests and create a database *per test run*.

I'd like to extend this functionality and add the capability to drop the database after each test has run. This lead me to the `Drop` trait, in which I would execute the `DROP DATABASE` command and call it a day (I'd store the db name and its connection/pool so I could access it later).

The problem, though, is that the app hangs at executing the `DROP DATABASE` query and and times out after 60 seconds. I don't know what's causing this as I am unable to print or debug the connection.

Here's the code that I have:

```rust
use futures::executor;
use sqlx::{Connection, Executor, PgConnection, PgPool};
use std::net::TcpListener;
use uuid::Uuid;
use zero2prod::configuration::{get_configuration, DatabaseSettings};

const BASE_URL: &str = "127.0.0.1";
pub struct TestApp {
    db_name: String,
    connection_string: String,
    pub address: String,
    pub db_pool: PgPool,
    pub connection: PgConnection,
}

/**
 * We need to refactor our project into a library and a binary: all our logic will live in the library crate
while the binary itself will be just an entrypoint with a very slim main function
 */

pub async fn init(url: &str) -> TestApp {
    let mut app = spawn_app().await;
    app.address = format!("{}{}", app.address, url);
    return app;
}

// Launch our application in the background ~somehow~
async fn spawn_app() -> TestApp {
    // We take the BASE_URL const and assign it a port 0. We then
    // pass the listener to the server
    let base_url = format!("{}:0", BASE_URL);
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(base_url).expect("Failed to bind random port");

    // We retrieve the port assigned by the OS
    let port = listener.local_addr().unwrap().port();

    let (connection, db_connection, db_name, connection_string) = init_db().await;

    // We pass the port now to our server
    let server = zero2prod::run(listener, db_connection.clone()).expect("Failed to bind address");
    let _ = actix_web::rt::spawn(server);
    let address = format!("http://{}:{}", BASE_URL, port);

    TestApp {
        db_name: String::from(db_name),
        address,
        db_pool: db_connection,
        connection,
        connection_string,
    }
}

async fn init_db() -> (PgConnection, PgPool, String, String) {
    let mut configuration = get_configuration().expect("Failed to read configuration");

    // We change the db name in each run as we need to run the test multiple times
    configuration.database.database_name = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();

    let (connection, pool) = configure_database(&configuration.database).await;

    return (
        connection,
        pool,
        String::from(&configuration.database.database_name),
        configuration.database.connection_string_without_db(),
    );
}

async fn configure_database(config: &DatabaseSettings) -> (PgConnection, PgPool) {

   // The following returns:
   //   format!(
   //       "postgres://{}:{}@{}:{}",
   //       self.username, self.password, self.host, self.port
   //   )
    let mut connection = PgConnection::connect(&config.connection_string_without_db())
        .await
        .expect("Failed to connect to Postgres.");

    connection
        .execute(format!(r#"CREATE DATABASE "{}""#, config.database_name).as_str())
        .await
        .expect("Failed to create the db");

    // Migrate the database

    let connection_pool = PgPool::connect(&config.connection_string())
        .await
        .expect("Failed to connect to Postgres");

    sqlx::migrate!("./migrations")
        .run(&connection_pool)
        .await
        .expect("Failed to migrate db");

    return (connection, connection_pool);
```

The entry point is the `init()` function which basically returns a TestApp struct (which originally contained the `db_pool` and `address` fields). Everything on the code above is working.

The problem is down below. Here's everything that I've tried:

1. Using Smol's runtime to run async in drop - Tried initializing a new connection to the Postgres database

```rust
impl Drop for TestApp {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        smol::block_on(async {
            let mut connection = PgConnection::connect(&self.connection_string)
                .await
                .expect("Failed to connect to Postgres.");

            let result = connection
                .execute(format!(r#"DROP DATABASE "{}""#, self.db_name).as_str())
                .await
                .expect("Error while querying the drop database");
            println!("{:?}", result);
        });
    }
}
```

2. Using Smol's runtime to run async in drop - tried using the exiting db_pool

```rust
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        smol::block_on(async {
            let result = self
                .db_pool
                .execute(format!(r#"DROP DATABASE "{}""#, self.db_name).as_str())
                .await.expect("Error while querying");
            println!("{:?}", result);
        });
    }
```

3. Using Future's crate executor - using the existing db_pool

```rust
     let result = executor::block_on(
            self.db_pool
                .execute(format!(r#"DROP DATABASE "{}""#, self.db_name).as_str()),
        )
        .expect("Failed to drop database");

        println!("{:?}", result);
```

4. Using Future's crate executor - Running `db_pool.acquire()` and then the pool (This hangs at `db_pool.acquire`.

```rust
     executor::block_on(self.db_pool.acquire()).expect("Failed to acquire pool");
     let result = executor::block_on(
            self.db_pool
                .execute(format!(r#"DROP DATABASE "{}""#, self.db_name).as_str()),
        )
        .expect("Failed to drop database");

        println!("{:?}", result);
```

5. Using Future's crate executor - Running the existing connection.

```rust
        let result = executor::block_on(
            self.connection
                .execute(format!(r#"DROP DATABASE "{}""#, self.db_name).as_str()),
        )
        .expect("Failed to drop database");

        println!("{:?}", result);
```

Note that the code isn't the prettiest, as I'm trying to find a working solution first.

Unfortunately I don't know what the problem is as there are no errors thrown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is smol the executor that you are using for your other async stuff?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement an async Drop in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782278/how-do-i-implement-an-async-drop-in-rust)

Comment: @PitaJ Nope. It's an actix web application, and I'm wrapping around the tests with a `#[actix_web::test]`. I did check that SO post, which is how I ended up implementing Smol or the Futures crate. 

My problem here seems that the query is somehow hanging and I can't debug it properly. Wanted to know if I was doing this right, or there was some sort of trick to it.

Comment: You can't use a different executor like that unfortunately, because the tokio APIs have to run under tokio.

Comment: I'd recommend using something like the answer for the linked Q there from Dan or like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1506af040cebd2cb49258906474c54e1) using a separate thread for the drop.

Comment: Oh nice, @PitaJ, thanks. I'll check it out and post back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### sqlx >0.6.1 update

The solution by @Ziliang Lin is indeed much cleaner now that `sqlx::test` is supported in sqlx. My implementation looks like this:

```
// Start the app
async fn spawn_app(pool: Pool<Postgres>) -> TestApp {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:0").expect("Failed to bind random port");
    let port = listener.local_addr().unwrap().port();

    let address = format!("http://127.0.0.1:{}", port);

    let server = run(listener, pool.clone()).expect("Failed to bind address");
    let _ = tokio::spawn(server);
    TestApp {
        address,
        db_pool: pool,
    }
}

// sqlx::test will automatically create the database, run migrations,
// and delete the database when the test is complete
#[sqlx::test]
async fn health_check_works(pool: Pool<Postgres>) {
    let app = spawn_app(pool).await;
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    // Act
    let response = client
        // Use the returned application address
        .get(&format!("{}/health_check", &app.address))
        .send()
        .await
        .expect("Failed to execute request.");

    // Assert
    assert!(response.status().is_success());
    assert_eq!(Some(0), response.content_length());
}
```

Just update all test routines from `tokio::test` -> `sqlx::test`, delete the `configure_database` functions, and add the `pool: Pool<Postgres>` argument to the test functions.

### Original post

I ran into this same issue. Thanks to some of the answers here, I ended up with the following solution (Note that I added an assertion for the db name starting with "test_db-", so you'll have to prepend your database names or delete the assertion):

```
pub struct TestApp {
    pub address: String,
    pub db_pool: PgPool,
    pub db_name: String,
    pub db_connection_string: String,
}

impl TestApp {
    async fn terminate(&mut self) {
        assert!(self.db_name.starts_with("test_db-"));
        println!("Cleaning up database: {}", self.db_name);
        self.db_pool.close().await;
        let mut connection = PgConnection::connect(&self.db_connection_string)
            .await
            .expect("Failed to connect to Postgres");

        // Force drop all active connections to database
        // TODO: see if there is a softer way to handle this (i.e. close connection when DB access is complete)
        connection
            .execute(
                format!(
                    r#"
                    SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
                    FROM pg_stat_activity
                    WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '{}'
                    AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
                    "#,
                    self.db_name
                )
                .as_str(),
            )
            .await
            .expect("Failed to terminate current connections to test db");

        connection
            .execute(format!(r#"DROP DATABASE "{}";"#, self.db_name).as_str())
            .await
            .expect("Failed to drop database.");
        println!("Database cleaned up successfully.")
    }
}

impl Drop for TestApp {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        std::thread::scope(|s| {
            s.spawn(|| {
                let runtime = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
                    .enable_all()
                    .build()
                    .unwrap();
                runtime.block_on(self.terminate());
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is working on my end! Sometimes my tests hang, but I don't know if this may be the culprit

Answer (score 2):

For people later meeting this question, I would suggest having a look at sqlx's [sqlx::test](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/attr.test.html)

This procedural macro would achieve what the OP wants to do automatically:

1. create a database for each integration test annotated by `[sqlx::test]`
2. drop the database after the test run

here's my code sample:

```rust
#[sqlx::test]
async fn confirmations_without_token_rejected_with_400(pool: Pool<Postgres>) -> Result<()> {
    // here I am using sea_orm, so I would do the migration inside `get_test_ap`
    let app = get_test_app(pool).await?;
    let cli = &app.cli;
    let resp = cli.get("/subscriptions/confirm").send().await;
    resp.assert_status(StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST);
    Ok(())
}
```

if you are using pure `sqlx`, you could just follow the link above and find the following example:

```rust
use sqlx::PgPool;

#[sqlx::test(migrations = "foo_migrations")]
async fn basic_test(pool: PgPool) -> sqlx::Result<()> {
    let mut conn = pool.acquire().await?;

    sqlx::query("SELECT * FROM foo")
        .fetch_one(&mut conn)
        .await?;
        
    assert_eq!(foo.get::<String>("bar"), "foobar!");
    
    Ok(())
}
```