# Is there a way to use tokio::main with a single threaded runtime in tokio 0.2?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Is there a way to specify a single-threaded runtime using the attribute `#[tokio::main]` in tokio 0.2? The [doc](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.20/tokio/runtime/index.html#runtime-configurations) does not seem to have examples for that.

EDIT:  I wanted to find a way to set up tokio runtime so that `rustc` is aware of `tokio:spawn()` will not be a new thread.

Answer (score 9):

#### Newer answer, applicable for Tokio 0.3.0 and above

The documentation for [`tokio::main`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/attr.main.html) shows what options it has.
It is quite common to want to start the current-thread runtime, so there is a special option for it:

```rust
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
```

#### Old answer, applicable for Tokio < 0.3.0

The documentation for [`tokio::main`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/attr.main.html) shows what options it has:

> `core_threads=n` - Sets core threads to n (requires rt-threaded feature).
> `max_threads=n` - Sets max threads to n (requires rt-core or rt-threaded feature).

Thus:

```
#[tokio::main(core_threads = 1, max_threads = 1)]
async fn main() {
    println!("Hello world");
}
```

If this does not work for whatever your case is, you will have to directly create a runtime as shown in [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have clarified that I wanted to find a way to have tokio executor runs on the single (current) thread,  instead of thread pool of size 1.  The reason is that I wanted `rustc` is aware of all tasks are in a single thread, so no need to check for thread safety issues. Later I tried the approach of using `basic_scheduler`, but it seems that `rustc` still thinks it's a new thread when I call `tokio::spawn()`.

Comment: @user1783732 why wouldn’t you have asked the question you wanted to solve? You are demonstrating the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your problem [isn’t unique to Tokio or async](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423) and shows a fundamental misunderstanding of what the Rust compiler is capable of.

Comment: @user1783732 You can use [LocalSet](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.LocalSet.html) and `spawn_local` to limit execution to a single thread. It allows having `!Send` variable over `.await` boundary, which sounds like what you're looking for.