# How to use async/await in Rust when you can't make main function async

Tags: rust, async-await

I have a function to download a file which is async:

```
async fn download_file() {
    fn main() {
        let resp = reqwest::blocking::get("https://sh.rustup.rs").expect("request failed");
        let body = resp.text().expect("body invalid");
        let mut out = File::create("rustup-init.sh").expect("failed to create file");
        io::copy(&mut body.as_bytes(), &mut out).expect("failed to copy content");
    }
}
```

I want to call this function to download a file and then await it when I need it. 
But the problem is if I do it like this, I get an error:

```
fn main() {
    let download = download_file();
    // Do some work
    download.await; // `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks\nonly allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
    // Do some work
}
```

So I have to make the main function async, but when I do that I get another error:

```
async fn main() { // `main` function is not allowed to be `async`\n`main` function is not allowed to be `async`"
    let download = download_file();
    // Do some work
    download.await;
    // Do some work
}
```

So how can I use async and await 
Thanks for helping

Comment: Related: [Do you always need an async fn main() if using async in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62309065/do-you-always-need-an-async-fn-main-if-using-async-in-rust)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The most commonly used runtime, tokio, provides an attribute macro so that you can make your main function async:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let download = download_file().await;
}
```

In case you don't have a dependency on tokio just yet, add the following to your `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
```

Comment: as of 10/18/22, Cargo.toml statement for tokio is `tokio = { version = "1.21.2", features = ["full"] }`, not `tokio = "1.21.2"`

Comment: @JohnMiller you don't need `full`, just runtime and macro features are enough

Answer (score 8):

An established pattern for this is [here](https://thomask.sdf.org/blog/2021/03/08/bridging-sync-async-code-in-rust.html).

From a synchronous block, build a new runtime then call `block_on()` on it:

```
let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap();

let res = rt.block_on(async { something_async(&args).await });
```

Answer (score 3):

you can not make run as async because there must be a parent thread which is going to poll the result of main function. if main is itself is async then who is going to poll main? the return type of a async function is always something like this, impl future<output= Sometype + sometrait(if exist)> . the future tarit also provide the poll method so that the executor may know when to proceed .
See rust asyn prog. in rust to understand more in dept,
you can call block_on(some async task) in main method, which will block the current thread ie main until the given async task is not finished, on the other hand , await does not block the current thread. which is why a function which use .await must be async at first place

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer OP's (simple) question of just wanting to know how to actually run their async code, and @msrd0's answer shows the simpest usecase >95% of async Rust users will be happy with.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [async-std](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/) as your async implementation.

Your `Cargo.toml` should have this:

```
[dependencies]
async-std = {version = "1.12.0", features = ["attributes"]}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run async function into non async with `tokio::runtime`:

```rust
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

async fn async_bar() -> String {
    println!("run async bar");
    String::from("return async bar")
}

fn non_async_foo() {
    let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
    
    let future = async_bar();
    let r = rt.block_on(future);
    
    println!("{r}");
}

fn main() {
    non_async_foo();
}
```

This example working for me with `tokio` features = ["full"]

Or better way use `futures::executor` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74624227/8111346