# Why doesn't the second await get called on tokio::spawn?

Tags: rust

I have the following function that connects to a database using sqlx):

```
async fn testConnect() -> anyhow::Result<PgPool> {
    delay_for(Duration::from_millis(3000)).await;
    let pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(5)
        .connect(&"database_connection_string")
        .await?;

    Ok(pool)
}
```

And I run it on the tokio runtime:

```
let mut threaded_rt = runtime::Builder::new()
    .threaded_scheduler()
    .enable_all()
    .build()
    .unwrap();
threaded_rt.block_on(future::lazy(move |_| {
    let handle = tokio::spawn(testConnect());
    return handle;
}));
```

Any code after `delay_for` inside `testConnect` does not get executed. Why is this and how can I make both `await`s run?

If I remove the `delay_for` line of code, the database connection code runs as expected.

Comment: how do you know ? Do you wait your task ?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: You might as well use `#[tokio::main]`. See [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the following happens. This is analogue to starting a background worker thread and quit without joining it.

- you spawn the task on tokio and return the handle
- `block_on` drives the tokio reactor for a little while which is just enough for a normal connection, but not enough for the delay to expire
- nothing drives the reactor anymore, so the result of the spawned task is just dropped and the program exits

If so, you can fix it simply by calling `threaded_rt.block_on(testConnect())` directly, the `spawn()` part seems to be completely pointless.