# How can I get JSON from the Github API?

Tags: rest, http, rust, github-api, reqwest

I just want to get a JSON from the following URL.

So I used this code:

```
extern crate reqwest;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let res = reqwest::Client::new()
        .get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat")
        .send()?
        .text()?;
    println!("{}", res);

    Ok(())
}
```

But I don't know how to solve the error :

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be applied to values that implement `std::ops::Try`
  --> src\main.rs:19:15
   |
19 |       let res = reqwest::Client::new()
   |  _______________^
20 | |         .get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat")
21 | |         .send()?
   | |________________^ the `?` operator cannot be applied to type `impl std::future::Future`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required by `std::ops::Try::into_result`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `Desktop`.
```

but I can also obtain what I want with a simple

```
curl https://api.github.com/users/octocat
```

I've tried to add `use std::ops::Try;` but it doesn't work better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521201/how-do-i-synchronously-return-a-value-calculated-in-an-asynchronous-future-in-st)

Comment: The method `.send` in this version of reqwest is asynchronous. It returns a future, which needs to be executed to completion. Follow the [documentation for reqwest](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.8/reqwest/) for a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `reqwest` crate uprovides an asynchronous api by default. Therefore you have to `.await` before handling the error with the `?` operator. You also have to use an async runtime, such as `tokio`:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  let resp = reqwest::Client::new()
    .get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat")
    .send()
    .await?
    .json::<std::collections::HashMap<String, String>>()
    .await?;
  println!("{:#?}", resp);
  Ok(())
}
```

Note that to use convert the response to json as shown above, you must enable the `json` feature in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
reqwest = { version = "0.10.8", features = ["json"] }
```

If you don't want to use an async runtime, you can enable the blocking `reqwest` client:

```
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.10", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
```

And use it like so:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  let resp = reqwest::blocking::Client::new()
    .get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat")
    .send()?
    .json::<std::collections::HashMap<String, String>>()?;
  println!("{:#?}", resp);
  Ok(())
}
```

Github's api requires a couple other config options. Here is a minimal working example with reqwest and the github api:

```rust
use reqwest::header::{HeaderMap, HeaderValue, USER_AGENT};
use serde::{Deserialize};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
  // add the user-agent header required by github
  headers.insert(USER_AGENT, HeaderValue::from_static("reqwest"));

  let resp = reqwest::blocking::Client::new()
    .get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat")
    .headers(headers)
    .send()?
    .json::<GithubUser>()?;
  println!("{:#?}", resp);
  Ok(())
}

// Note that there are many other fields
// that are not included for this example
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct GithubUser {
  login: String,
  id: usize,
  url: String,
  #[serde(rename = "type")]
  ty: String,
  name: String,
  followers: usize
}
```

Comment: I obtain a warning and a Error :

warning: crate `Desktop` should have a snake case name
  |
  = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default
  = help: convert the identifier to snake case: `desktop`

Error: reqwest::Error { kind: Decode, source: Error("expected value", line: 2,
column: 1) }

And it compile !
But I don't have my json ...

I tried to use 
#[warn(non_snake_case)]
But nothing change

Comment: And I add 
use std::collections::HashMap;
in your code to work

Comment: The error you are receiving `Error(expected value)` does not have anything to do with `reqwest`. Convert the request with `.text()` instead of `.json()` an error returned by the github api: `Request forbidden by administrative rules.`

Comment: @WolodiaZDETOVETZKY I added a minimal example to my answer.