# rust tokio: calling async function from sync closure

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I have the following problem:
I'm trying to call `sync` closure from `async` function, but `sync closure` has to later call another `async` function.

I cannot make async closure, because they are unstable at the moment:
`error[E0658]: async closures are unstable`

so I have to do it this way somehow.

I found a couple of questions related to the problem, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521201/how-do-i-synchronously-return-a-value-calculated-in-an-asynchronous-future-in-st), but when I tried to implement it, im receiving the following error:

```
Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. 
This happens because a function (like `block_on`)
 attempted to block the current thread while the 
thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.'
```

here is [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=afa25fa0fa4f59b7577c4e0798971dd6) which hopefully can show what I'm having problem with.

I'm using tokio as stated in the title.

Comment: You can make a closure returning async block - `|| async { ... }` instead of `async || { ... }`.

Comment: To elaborate, here's your playground with the suggested change: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cc987ff5c41352ddc447a6724ae6abc8

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you very much, seems like it is way to go for now. Just for future readers I'll leave comment that now, since closure returns async block (instead of normal as previously) closure should be called with .awat

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, Tokio doesn't allow you to have nested runtimes.

There's a section in the documentation for Tokio's `Mutex` which states the following ([link](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.24/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#which-kind-of-mutex-should-you-use)):

> [It] is ok and often preferred to use the ordinary Mutex from the standard library in asynchronous code. [...] the feature that the async mutex offers over the blocking mutex is that it is possible to keep the mutex locked across an `.await` point, which is rarely necessary for data.

Additionally, from Tokio's [mini-Redis](https://github.com/tokio-rs/mini-redis/blob/master/src/db.rs#L34-L40) example:

> A Tokio mutex is mostly intended to be used when locks need to be held
> across `.await` yield points. All other cases are **usually** best
> served by a std mutex. If the critical section does not include any
> async operations but is long (CPU intensive or performing blocking
> operations), then the entire operation, including waiting for the mutex,
> is considered a "blocking" operation and `tokio::task::spawn_blocking`
> should be used.

If the `Mutex` is the only `async` thing you need in your synchronous call, it's most likely better to make it a blocking `Mutex`. In that case, you can lock it from `async` code by first calling `try_lock()`, and, if that fails, attempting to lock it in a blocking context via `spawn_blocking`.

Comment: This doesn't really help me, as behind mutex there is `async` socket, which I write to from both async function and the mentioned closure. I guess I could make socket sync and then call spawn blocking from every async function that ever tries to write to this socket, but that seems ugly.