# Calling async function inside an iterator

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, future

I want to `await` an `async` function inside a closure used in an iterator. The function requiring the closure is called inside a struct implementation. I can't figure out how to do this.

This code simulates what I'm trying to do:

```rust
struct MyType {}

impl MyType {
    async fn foo(&self) {
        println!("foo");

        (0..2).for_each(|v| {
            self.bar(v).await;
        });
    }

    async fn bar(&self, v: usize) {
        println!("bar: {}", v);
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mt = MyType {};
    mt.foo().await;
}
```

Obviously, this will not work since the closure is not `async`, giving me:

```
error[E0728]: `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
7 |         (0..2).for_each(|v| {
  |                         --- this is not `async`
8 |             self.bar(v).await;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
```

After looking for an answer on how to call an `async` function from a non-`async` one, I eded up with this:

```rust
tokio::spawn(async move {
    self.bar(v).await;
});
```

But now I'm hitting lifetime issues instead:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
 --> src/main.rs:4:18
  |
4 |     async fn foo(&self) {
  |                  ^^^^^
  |                  |
  |                  this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
  |                  ...is captured here...
...
8 |             tokio::spawn(async move {
  |             ------------ ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
```

This also doesn't surprise me since from what I understand the Rust compiler cannot know how long a thread will live. Given this, the thread spawned with `tokio::spawn` might outlive the type `MyType`.

The first fix I came up with was to make `bar` an associate function, copy everything I need in my closure and pass it as a value to `bar` and call it with `MyType::bar(copies_from_self)` but this is getting ugly since there's a lot of copying. It also feels like a workaround for not knowing how lifetimes work.

I was instead trying to use `futures::executor::block_on` which works for simple tasks like the one in this post:

```rust
(0..2).for_each(|v| {
    futures::executor::block_on(self.bar(v));
});
```

But when putting this in my real life example where I use a third party library<sup>1</sup> which also uses `tokio`, things no longer work. After reading the documentation, I realise that `#[tokio::main]` is a macro that eventually wraps everything in `block_on` so by doing this there will be nested `block_on`. This might be the reason why one of the `async` methods called in `bar` just stops working without any error or logging (works without `block_on` so shouldn't be anything with the code). I reached out to the authors who said that I could use `for_each(|i| async move { ... })` which  made me even more confused.

```rust
(0..2).for_each(|v| async move {
    self.bar(v).await;
});
```

Will result in the compilation error

```
expected `()`, found opaque type`
```

which I think makes sense since I'm now returning a future and not `()`. My naive approach to this was to try and await the future with something like this:

```rust
(0..2).for_each(|v| {
    async move {
        self.bar(v).await;
    }
    .await
});
```

But that takes me back to square one, resulting in the following compilation error which I also think makes sense since I'm now back to using `await` in the closure which is `sync`.

```
only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks` since the
```

This discovery also makes it hard for me to make use of answers such as the ones found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65837485/rust-tokio-calling-async-function-from-sync-closure#comment116418200_65837485) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521201/how-do-i-synchronously-return-a-value-calculated-in-an-asynchronous-future-in-st).

The question after all this cargo cult programming is basically, **is it possible, and if so how do I call my `async` function from the closure** (and preferably without spawning a thread to avoid lifetime problems) in an iterator? If this is not possible, what would an idiomatic implementation for this look like?

---

<sup>1</sup>[This is the library/method used](https://docs.rs/serenity/0.10.2/serenity/model/id/struct.ChannelId.html#method.send_message)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Iterator::for_each` expects a synchronous closure, thus you can't use `.await` in it (not directly at least), nor can you return a future from it.

One solution is to just use a `for` loop instead of `.for_each`:

```rust
for v in 0..2 {
    self.bar(v).await;
}
```

The more general approach is to use [streams](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/prelude/trait.Stream.html) instead of iterators, since those are the asynchronous equivalent (and the equivalent methods on streams are typically asynchronous as well). This would work not only for `for_each` but for most other iterator methods:

```rust
use futures::prelude::*;

futures::stream::iter(0..2)
    .for_each(|c| async move {
        self.bar(v).await;
    })
    .await;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The actual iterator is not a `for_each` but [`try_for_each`](https://docs.rs/egg-mode/0.15.0/egg_mode/stream/index.html). This means I cannot really change to a `for` loop nor use `futures::stream::iter`. Given this, do you see any other solution than using `tokio::spawn` and copy all data I need from `self`?

Comment: I realise now that there's maye a way to use [`TwitterStream`](https://docs.rs/egg-mode/0.15.0/egg_mode/stream/struct.TwitterStream.html) other than `try_for_each`? Will try to see if I can figure something out.

Comment: Your answer made me read about streams and realise I **was** working with a stream. I changed `stream.try_for_each(|m| {})` to `while let Some(x) = stream.try_next().await.unwrap() {}` which made me not use a closure. Thank you so much!