How to do a blocking read with timeout with tokio-tungstenite?
Is there a straightforward API to block with timeout on reading the next websocket message in tokio-tungstenite?
Right now, I have:
read.next().await
where read is a SplitStream<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>>
This will block "forever" until it receives a message or error (eg. OS forces the socket closed).
What I'd like to do is read.next(timeout).await which will either wait for a message/error, or it will give up after the timeout.
Is there some way to do this?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68294549/5397009

tokio has a function timeout(Duration, F:Future) that will block on a Future with a timeout.
This particular case creates a bit of nesting to be destructured. For example:
match timeout(Duration::from_secs(100), read.next()).await {
  Err(elapsed) => // timed out
  Ok(None)     => // read.next returned None
  Ok(Some(msg)) => match msg {
    Ok(Message::Text(text)) => // 
    // ...
    Err(e) => // Error receiving the message
  }
}

