# How to process every value in a HashMap and optionally reject some?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I would like to process the values from a `HashMap` one by one, while maybe removing some of them.

For example, I would like to do an equivalent of:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn example() {
    let mut to_process = HashMap::new();
    to_process.insert(1, true);

    loop {
        // get an arbitrary element
        let ans = to_process.iter().next().clone(); // get an item from the hash
        match ans {
            Some((k, v)) => {
                if condition(&k,&v) {
                    to_process.remove(&k);
                }
            }
            None => break, // work finished
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails to compile:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `to_process` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:12:17
   |
9  |         let ans = to_process.iter().next().clone();
   |                   ---------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
12 |                 to_process.remove(&k);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^------^^^^
   |                 |          |
   |                 |          immutable borrow later used by call
   |                 mutable borrow occurs here
```

I know I really would need https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27804 (which is for `HashSet` but for `HashMap` would be the same)
and I cannot implement the provided solutions without having a non-mut and mutable reference still or using unsafe.

Is there a simple way I am missing?

Comment: I notice that the `.clone()` does nothing useful -- because `next()` returns `Option<(&K, &V)>`, it just copies the references. If you wanted to get an `Option<(K, V)>` by cloning you would need something like `.map(|(k, v)| (k.clone(), v.clone()))` (but it seems unlikely you would need to).

Comment: very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/45724517/5986907

Comment: Does edwardw's answer work for you or are you still waiting for something different?

Comment: not exactly, I wasn't very clear : I updated the title and (bad) example to better reflect my intentions : consume elements from the map, and maybe add back

Comment: I guess this was a translation error from my side. Since the answer was interesting and did correspond the original, different question, I will revert my edit, choose an answer and then post a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note** If you need to alter keys or add kvps to the `HashMap` during processing, see @edwardw's answer. Otherwise ...

Use [`HashMap::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.retain). You can change your process function to return a `bool` indicating whether to keep that key value pair. For example

```
let mut to_process: HashMap<u32, String> = HashMap::new();
to_process.insert(1, "ok".to_string());
to_process.insert(2, "bad".to_string());

to_process.retain(process);
    
fn process(k: &u32, v: &mut String) -> bool {
    // do stuff with k and v
    v == "ok"
}
```

Comment: interesting, but the goal of my processing step is that in some cases, I need to _add_ elements to to_process (say like with a list of possible options).

Comment: @makapuf you should update the question and title to reflect that - the comment in your code snippet is off screen and not obvious

Answer (score 4):

This looks like an awfully good fit for [`Iterator::filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map):

> The closure must return an `Option<T>`. `filter_map` creates an iterator which calls this closure on each element. If the closure returns `Some(element)`, then that element is returned. If the closure returns `None`, it will try again, and call the closure on the next element, seeing if it will return `Some`.

The following `process_and_maybe_add` is very simple, but you get the idea:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut data = HashMap::new();
    data.insert(1, "a");
    data.insert(2, "b");
    data.insert(3, "c");

    let processed = data
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(process_and_maybe_add)
        .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
    dbg!(processed);
}

fn process_and_maybe_add((k, v): (u32, &str)) -> Option<(u32, String)> {
    if k % 2 != 0 {
        Some((k + 100, v.to_owned() + v))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```